# Subtraction from number python3

Tags: python

Not long ago I did make a simple calk in free time, but after wanting improve it got stack in the problem with function that clear only one number. I did play with it for a little and most errors come with: "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'". I start learning programming not long ago, so a little spanky some times. Can someone help me to understand what goes wrong?

Here what i did so far, part of code:

```
numOf = ""
numberEt = StringVar()

CalkEntry = Entry(calk, textvariable = numberEN).grid(row = 0, column = 1, columnspan = 8)

def butPress(num):
    global numOf
    numOf = numOf + str(num)
    numberEt.set(numOf)

def varPress():
    global numOf
    total = str(eval(numOf))
    numberEt.set(total)


def Clear():
    global numOf
    numOf = ""
    numberEt.set("")

def BClear():
    global numOf
    numOf = numOf - 1
    numberEt.set(numOf)
```

Comment: OK your problem is that you re trying to do arithmetic on a string! You need to change `numOf = numOf -1` to `numOf = str(int(numOf) -1))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't clear to me why you are using numbers as string but your problem is in the `Bclear()` function:

```
def BClear():
    global numOf
    numOf = str(int(numOf) - 1)
    numberEt.set(numOf)
```

While the operand sign `+` is acceptable for string types since it concatenates strings, the operand `-` cannot be used.

Be careful working with strings as `str(4) + str(5)` means `45`, not `9`

Comment: I don't really remember, why i did use string, maybe because of entry. Thanks for the answer, i did understand how to work with it. But i have question then, how i can come to using numbers as number ?